# Magento 2.2.3 CE, price is zero when adding to cart

Tags: price, addtocart, magento2.2.3, cash-on-delivery

I have a very strange issue. After upgrading from 2.1.3 to 2.2.3 CE I've noticed one strange issue, which is as I found out, related to MSP_CashOnDelivery module. But please let me explain the scenario.

When the module is disabled, add to cart works properly, and mini-cart is displayed after product is added to cart. But, when the module is enabled data this is not the case.

Here are the call and the response:

/en/customer/section/load/?sections=cart&update_section_id=false&_=1525081553687

```
cart
{
    summary_count: 0,
    subtotalAmount: null,
    subtotal: "<span class="price">AED0.00</span>",
    data_id: 1525081565,
    extra_actions: "",
    isGuestCheckoutAllowed: true,
THIS => items: [] <= THIS,
    possible_onepage_checkout: true,
    subtotal: "<span class="price">AED0.00</span>",
    subtotalAmount: null,
    subtotal_excl_tax: "<span class="price">AED0.00</span>",
    subtotal_incl_tax: "<span class="price">AED0.00</span>",
    summary_count: 0,
    website_id: "1"
}
```

Did anyone have a similar case, because I still can't find what exactly is causing this issue.

Comment: Are you using below module?
https://github.com/magespecialist/MSP_CashOnDelivery
Because, Here They have mentioned that,"MSP CashOnDelivery is a Magento 1.x extension ..."

Comment: Previous version I had (2.1.3) has this module enabled and it works without any issues. I have the latest version of M2 version of this module.